# Puppeteer clicking a <td> after selecting it

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I tested my xpath selector in chrome dev tools and it finds the `<td>` I am trying to select.

I tried a handful of ways, using page.x$, then made sure the element was getting selected properly with the below:

```
page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]")
.then(selector => {
    page.click(selector);
})
```

Execution does reach the `page.click()`, and I get the below error. I am confused because I didn't think I was changing contexts.
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created!`

Edit: here is the HTML code. It is an Angular grid made with an HTML table. The `<td>` is at the bottom.
[image]

Here is the rest of the code. Everything else is working fine. Sorry if this is clunky.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const kindle = puppeteer.devices['Kindle Fire HDX landscape'];

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //go to page and log in
    await page.emulate(kindle);
    await page.goto('http://localhost:4201/#/login');
    await page.waitForSelector('input[id="usr"]');
    await page.type('#usr', 'myusername');
    await page.type('#pwd', '');
    await page.click('button');

    //wait for homepage to load
    await page.waitForSelector('#menuData');
    await page.click('#menuData');
    await page.waitForSelector('#drCreate');
    await page.click('#drCreate');
    await page.waitForSelector('.mat-input-element'); //a request piece is loaded
    //populate fields

    var date = new Date();

    await page.type('#mat-input-0', humanReadableDate(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    await page.type('#mat-input-1', humanReadableDate(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5)
    await page.type('#mat-input-3', humanReadableDate(date));

    await page.click('.pi-angle-double-right');

    page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]")
    .then(selector => {
        page.click(selector);
    })
}

function humanReadableDate(date) {
    if (!date) {
        date = new Date();
    }
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}

main();
```

Comment: Could you please add HTML code?

Comment: You are navigating in your code. Please add some more code.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I added my JS code and a screenshot of the generated Angular html code (Edit: Yevhen provided an answer that solved the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an invalid page context. Try something like this:

```
await page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]")
const [ projects ] = await page.$x("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]");
projects.click()
```

or short version:

```
page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]").then(selector => selector.click())
```

Comment: This works! Can you tell me why my original attempt was not working?

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

[`page.click`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) expects a string (the selector) as argument, but you are passing an element handle instead.

Quoting from the docs from [`page.waitForXPath`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options):

> returns: <Promise<?ElementHandle>> Promise which resolves when element specified by xpath string is added to DOM. Resolves to `null` if waiting for `hidden: true` and xpath is not found in DOM.

That means you cannot give the result from that function (an element handle) to `page.click`.

#### Solution

Instead you could write your code like this using [`elementHandle.click`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions):

```js
await page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]")
.then(elementHandle => elementHandle.click())
```

But I would recommend to use `async`/`await` syntax instead to be more conform with the rest of your code:

```js
const elementHandle = await page.waitForXPath("//td[contains(., 'All Projects')]");
await elementHandle.click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried this instead and it also works. I'll remember to check the expected argument types in the documentation if I run into an issue again.